# java.lang.AssertionError: 1 expectation failed. Expected status code <200> but was <500> - in restassured -Post endpoint test

Tags: java, post, rest-assured

I am new to RestAssured, trying to create a test for POST endpoint but it returns 500 when i am executing it. Not sure what the problem is.
Below mentioned is the code:

```
import static io.restassured.RestAssured.*;
import java.util.HashMap;

import org.json.simple.JSONObject;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeClass;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;
import io.restassured.RestAssured;
import io.restassured.http.ContentType;


public class Test01_CreateBooking {
    @Test
    public void CreateBooking() {
        JSONObject request = new JSONObject();
    
    request.put("firstname", "Tom");
    request.put("lastname", "Payconiq");
    request.put("totalprice", "677");
    request.put("depositpaid", "true");
    request.put("bookingdates.checkin", "2023-06-06");
    request.put("bookingdates.checkout", "2023-07-07");
    request.put("additionalneeds", "Breakfast");
        
    System.out.println(request.toJSONString());
     //baseURI = "https://restful-booker.herokuapp.com/booking";
    
    given().
        header("Content-Type", "application/json").
        contentType(ContentType.JSON).
        accept(ContentType.JSON).
        body(request.toJSONString()).
    when().
        post("https://restful-booker.herokuapp.com/booking").
    then().
        statusCode(200)
        .log().all();
    }
    
}
```

I am expecting a 200 and the record should be created but it retuns 500.Can someone please help.

Comment: 500 is server error. That basically means `there were some kind of error`. We can't help you and it completely depends on your API maintainers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its because the json body you are sending is invalid , you are expecting json simple

```
bookingdates.checkin
```

to convert to below nested key which won't work, it will treat it as a key only

```
 "bookingdates": {
            "checkin": ""
        }
```

What you are sending is this

```
{
    "firstname": "Tom",
    "additionalneeds": "Breakfast",
    "bookingdates.checkin": "2023-06-06",
    "bookingdates.checkout": "2023-07-07",
    "totalprice": "677",
    "depositpaid": "true",
    "lastname": "Payconiq"
}
```

and correct way is this

```
{
    "firstname": "Tom",
    "additionalneeds": "Breakfast",
    "bookingdates": {
        "checkin": "2023-06-06",
        "checkout": "2023-07-07"
    },
    "totalprice": "677",
    "depositpaid": "true",
    "lastname": "Payconiq"
}
```

You need to created a bookingdates object and then add more keys under it to get proper structure of json

use below code , should work fine

```
import static io.restassured.RestAssured.given;

import io.restassured.http.ContentType;
import org.json.simple.JSONObject;
import org.junit.Test;

public class Test01_CreateBooking {

    @Test
    public void CreateBooking() {
        JSONObject request = new JSONObject();

        request.put("firstname", "Tom");
        request.put("lastname", "Payconiq");
        request.put("totalprice", "677");
        request.put("depositpaid", "true");
        JSONObject bookingDates = new JSONObject();
        bookingDates.put("checkin", "2023-06-03");
        bookingDates.put("checkout", "2023-07-05");
        request.put("bookingdates", bookingDates);
        request.put("additionalneeds", "Breakfast");

        System.out.println(request.toJSONString());
        //baseURI = "https://restful-booker.herokuapp.com/booking";

        given().contentType(ContentType.JSON) .body(request.toJSONString()).when()
            .post("https://restful-booker.herokuapp.com/booking").then().statusCode(200).log()
            .all();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks alot, it worked. I was suspecting the same and that was it.

Comment: please accept the answer if your issue is resolved